# Is it possible to migrate a single file from one SVN repository to another while preserving history?

Tags: svn

I started a small application in my personal SVN repository. It's gained enough interest that it is worth moving development to a shared group repository. Can the application (only a single file) including its history be migrated to the group repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out 'svnadmin dump', 'svnadmin load' and 'svndumpfilter'

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate

Dump the repository with the file you want to move, use svndumpfilter to filter out only the paths for that file, then load the filtered dump into the shared repository.

Comment: thanks! I knew about svndump but had not heard of svndumpfilter.