# Share an existing svn project

Tags: eclipse, svn, import, google-code

I actually have an existing svn project hosted by google code. now I had created a new svn repository on my rented vServer.
Now I wanna share/copy my

```
https://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

into my new repo,which is available on

```
https://mydomain.com/svn/client/android/
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Export and import? Not sure what you mean by "share". Should the repos remain synced?

Comment: no, after finishing i'll delete the googlecode project, and I thought there were an "Team->Share" function into eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate your project to your vserver, I think [How do I migrate an SVN repository to another SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939963/how-to-migrate-svn-to-another-repository) is for you. If this is your solution, question is an exact duplicate.

Comment: I tried this, but svnadmin dump says, that he can use an url to dump

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939963/how-to-migrate-svn-to-another-repository#answer-3142938) suggests to use `svnsync`. How about that?